# What is the purpose of using packages in R?

Tags: r

I’ve been teaching myself R for data analysis/econometrics over the past few months, with a heavy focus on regression. I feel that I’ve been making slow but steady progress, but one thing which I’m still confused about is the functionality and necessity of “packages”. Please could you answer as simply as possible. Here are my two questions:

1. So far, I have really just been using the “AER” (Applied Econometrics for R) package, as this is what the textbook I have been following instructed. I don’t really understand why I need to use this package. Since R has a “base” statistics package constantly running anyway, what difference does it make? I understand that each package usually comes with unique datasets to work with, but what else does it offer apart from that? Do they offer special formulas or equations which you don’t get in the base statistics package?
2. Also, the graphics seem to be very limited and basic with packages. If packages do offer unique formulas, is it possible to run those packages simultaneously with ggplot2 so that I can get the best of both worlds (i.e. sophisticated formulas and beautiful graphics)? If packages don’t offer unique in-built formulas, then why don’t people just use ggoplot2 for absolutely everything?

Sorry if this seems like a lazy/silly question, but I’ve been searching on forums to no avail and it’s really frustrating me that I’m confused over something so elementary.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should!) [check the documentation of the AER package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-6) to answer this question.

In fact, that package offers a large number of data sets and a few functions (e.g. [a function to fit tobit regression models](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-6/topics/tobit)) for working with econometric data. Using the package (only) makes sense if you need these functions (or the data sets).

The same is true for other packages. In fact, you mention ggplot2. That’s a package! And it adds a lot of functionality, which you already seem to appreciate. Other packages extend R in other directions. Notably, there are several packages which extend or adapt ggplot2 graphics.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, Konrad. I have already read through the AER manual but can't see anything to do with unique functions. All I see is a large number of datasets which it comes with.

Comment: @CaveBear990 look at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-6/topics/dispersiontest

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack! Packages allow for expanded use beyond base R. Coding wise, packages can include ways for your code to look "cleaner" among other things.

For instance, the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/) package allows for piping operators which makes it easier to read and simplifies some of the base functions.